# Properties of Javelin Quiver?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, equipment

One of my players wishes to carry javelins.  It seems logical that these could be carried in a quiver (appropriately sized of course) that would reside on the wearer's back and would serve a similar function as a quiver does for arrows.

We cannot find any reference material for such a thing (how much it would cost, how many javelins it would hold).  Is there a place where such a thing is specified?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only mention of a special quiver for javelins is in the magic items list on page 189 of the DMG; the **Quiver of Ehlonna.**

This quiver has several extradimensional compartments to hold various ranged ammunition or similar sized items. Including up to 18 javelins or similarly sized medium items.

The Quiver of Ehlonna is only an uncommon wonderous item, so this solution isn't out of the realm of possibility to get pretty early in a campaign. Assuming you want to give out magic items of course.

The quiver in the Player's Handbook (Pg. 153) only mentions that it can hold 20 arrows. So, if you elect to give him a quiver that isn't magical, you would have to make the call as a DM as to the price and capacity of a quiver. Or just hand-wave the quiver away and say a person can only carry some number of javelins on their person that seems reasonable.

Comment: “Or just hand-wave the quiver away and say a person can only carry some number of javelins on their person that seems reasonable.” This is probably what's intended. Paladin starting equipment can include five javelins on top of two other weapons/shield. Nothing special is included in the starting equipment for carrying these. If you apply encumbrance rules then the javelins themselves naturally set an upper limit because of their 2lb weight.

Comment: Historically speaking, there were no "javelin quivers", a bundle of javelins were usually bound together with leather thong and carried.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any reference to a non-magical quiver for javelins, but there is a historical counter-part.

The Ottoman had infantry armed horsemen and infantry who had (metal?)quivers. But there's also plenty of examples with leather examples. Peltasts would just harry them in hand with leather straps along with their pelta (shield)

[Ottomon Jarid quiver](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8f/d0/de/8fd0de3c091b067f6f8ba41c0216c7f1.jpg)

[Thracian Peltast](http://pages.uoregon.edu/klio/maps/gr/peltast2.jpg)